# How to dimiss a UIAlertView when tapping anywhere on the window

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

I am opening alert popup on click button which is working fine the code is

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PopUP Title" 
                                                message:@"This is pop up window/ Alert" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *tempImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,50,50)];
tempImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];

[alert addSubView:tempImageView]

[alert show];
```

the alert box is closing on click of **Ok** button ,i don't want it, i wants to colse the alert box on click of any where on window .
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are essentially trying to recreate a "Toast" on iOS. Good news, someone has already done that. [See this project.](http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/)

**Edit:** Don't want to use iToast. I like your style, less code it is. Here is what I come up with. It would seem obvious as others have said that the only way to overcome the modal nature of the `UIAlertView` is to add a superview to handle touch events. But you don't have to do that manually every time, consider subclassing `UIAlertView`. Try something like this:

**Edit:** @wagashi, Thanks for accepting my answer, and thanks for the heads up about `setFrame:` being a good place to adjust the size. Your code does make a very toast-like little alert, however when I tried it I found that if the message was to long the view seemed to fall apart. So I have modified `setFrame:` to simply reduce the size of the alert by about the size of one button, and to remain centered on the screen. So that the class accurately answers the question title "iOS How to dismiss UIAlertView with one tap anywhere?"

**NoButtonAlertView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface _NoButtonAlertViewCover : UIView
@property (nonatomic,assign) UIAlertView *delegate;
@end
@interface NoButtonAlertView : UIAlertView
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message;
@end
```

**NoButtonAlertView.m**

```
#import "NoButtonAlertView.h"
@implementation _NoButtonAlertViewCover
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [_delegate dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
@end
@implementation NoButtonAlertView
-(void)show{
    [super show];
    _NoButtonAlertViewCover *cover = [[_NoButtonAlertViewCover alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    cover.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cover.backgroundColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.01];
    cover.delegate = self;
    [self.superview addSubview:cover];
}
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message{
    if ((self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil])){
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)rect {
    // Called multiple times, 4 of those times count, so to reduce height by 40
    rect.size.height -= 10;
    self.center = self.superview.center;
    [super setFrame:rect];
}
@end
```

With this simple `UIAlertView` subclass and its `UIView` subclass for a cover, you can use it as simply as you would a standard `UIAlertView`. Like so:

```
NoButtonAlertView *alert = [[NoButtonAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"I am the very model of a modern major general; I'm information, vegitable, animal, and mineral."];
[alert show];
```

Will yield:

[image: Custom AlertView]